# Как получить индекс элемента массива? (Vue JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for

Есть массив с todo листом. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку удаления у меня находился индекс элемента массива, который пользователь хочет удалить через цикл. Заранее извиняюсь, если код выглядит плохо. Я только начинаю программировать. Писал код на vue js.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      count: 0,
      list: [{
          id: 1,
          body: 'Покушать'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          body: 'Сходить в магазин'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    create() {
      const newList = {
        id: Date.now(),
        body: this.name
      }
      this.list.push(newList);
      this.name = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.todolist {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid orangered;
}

.input {
  border: 3px solid rgb(235, 165, 104);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.del {
  border: 2px solid orangered;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
}

.create {
  border: 2px solid rgb(52, 194, 52);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите задачу" class="input"> <br> <br>
    <button @click="create()" class="create">Создать</button> <br>
    <button class="del">Удалить</button>
  </form>
  <div class="todolist" v-for="(todolist,index,) in list">
    <div>
      Название: {{ todolist.body }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно в `div` записать в атрибут `data-id`...

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема в том, что кнопка удаления расположена в неудачном месте. Сколько действий пользователь должен сделать, чтобы удалить задачу? 1. Выбрать задачу, 2. нажать на кнопку вызова всплывающей формы, 3. нажать на кнопку удаления на форме. Многовато.

Comment: Для того, чтобы удалить элемент, нужно сперва его отметить (как-то выбрать) сейчас список выводится просто в `div`. Думаю логичнее кнопку удалить сделать рядом с каждым элементом списка, и в эту кнопку записывайте `id`. А потом создайте метод для удаления

Answer (score 1):

> Как получить индекс элемента массива?

Например вот так...

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      count: 0,
      select: null,
      list: [{
          id: 1,
          body: 'Покушать'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          body: 'Сходить в магазин'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    on(i) {
      if (this.select === i) i = null
      this.select = i
    },
    del() {
      if (this.select == null) return
      this.list.splice(this.select, 1)
      this.select = null
    },
    create() {
      const newList = {
        id: Date.now(),
        body: this.name
      }
      this.list.push(newList);
      this.name = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.todolist {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid orangered;
}
.todolist .on{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.input {
  border: 3px solid rgb(235, 165, 104);
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.del {
  border: 2px solid orangered;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
}

.create {
  border: 2px solid rgb(52, 194, 52);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent>
    <input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите задачу" class="input"> <br> <br>
    <button @click="create()" class="create">Создать</button> <br>
    <button @click="del()" class="del">Удалить</button>
  </form>
  <div class="todolist" v-for="(todolist,index,) in list">
    <div @click="on(index)" v-bind:class="{ on: select === index }">
      Название: {{ todolist.body }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```